# Can not show correct image when reload tableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem : I want to reload tableview but it only reload label, i can not reload image of button. This is my codes:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UILabel *FileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 30)];
        FileNameLabel.tag = 1000;
        FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSLog(@"AllItemsArrayarray: %@", AllItemsArray);
        //  FileNameLabel.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
        [FileNameLabel release];

        UILabel *UploadTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 150, 25)];
        UploadTimeLabel.tag = 2000;
        UploadTimeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UploadTimeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
        UploadTimeLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        // UploadTimeLabel.text = [UploadTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: UploadTimeLabel];
        [UploadTimeLabel release];
        UILabel *pricelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 80, 30)];


        pricelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        pricelabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        pricelabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        pricelabel.tag = 3000;
        //pricelabel.hidden = YES;
        pricelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview: pricelabel];
        [pricelabel release];

        market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        market.tag = 4000;


      //  [market addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

       // [market setTag:indexPath.row];
        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:market];
    }

    marketButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];
    if([sellingArray count]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"sellingArray %@",sellingArray);
        if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
        {

            [marketButton setSelected:NO];
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            marketButton.enabled = YES;

        }
        else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
        {

            [marketButton setSelected:YES];
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            marketButton.enabled = YES;
            // auctionButton.enabled = NO;
        }
    }
    [marketButton addTarget:self action:@selector(marketPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    //}


       if( [temp count] > 0)
    {
        UILabel *fileNameLbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
        fileNameLbl.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *uploadlbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2000];
        uploadlbl.text =[UploadTimeAllArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    if([priceNewArray count]> 0)
    {
        UILabel *pricelbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3000];
        pricelbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[priceNewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        if ([sellingArray count]>0) {
            if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"]){
                pricelbl.hidden = NO;
            }
            else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
                pricelbl.hidden = YES;

        }

        }


    }
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;   // match the button's size with the image size

    //[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // set the button's target to this table view controller so we can interpret touch events and map that to a NSIndexSet
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

     _tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0);

    return cell;
    }
```

I used above code, when call `[table reloaddata]` , all label reloaded except button (button market) not show correct image. I don't know why so. Can you give any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: I can see that you create/configure the market button when a cells needs to be created but not when a dequeued cell is used.

Comment: Sorry, can't see where your if clause ends. Try to remove everything except the market button and debug if your configuration code is reached.

Comment: I debug when reloadData, marketButton is 0x0000. it can not init ? @BerndRabe

Answer (score 0):

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` follows always the same pattern.
It dequeues a cell if it finds one and than it is up to you to configure it. If it can't find a cell (nil == cell) a new cell must be created, followed by the configuration step.

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    }
    // configure the market button
    return cell;
}
```

One general advise is to use storyboarding/Interface builder to configure the cells you need or subclass `UITableViewCell` to have your own cell. That would greatly simplify your code and improves readability.